# How to remove a listener

Tags: getstream-io

I set the listener when a new message arrives on the channel

```
conversation.on('message.new', async (event) => {
// code
});
```

When removing a participant from a channel, I need the `message.new` listener to be deleted. I call off() for listener.

```
conversation.on('member.removed', async (event) => {
   conversation.off('message.new', async (event) => {});
});
```

but the first listener is still working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save your listener to remove it later because it will be checked for equality. In your snippet, you're passing a new function so it's not removed.

```
const yourHandler = async (event) => {
  // code
}

// later

conversation.off(eventType, yourHandler);
```